# jquery, moving the current item to the top

Tags: jquery, scroll

The problem I'm having is that if the fourth item has a long description, it cuts off as it goes below #features (due to a strict high in my design with the overflow:hidden.

What I was hoping is someone would have a suggestion on how to make the current item selected to move to the top?

Here is an example url: forums.wuggawoo.co.uk/example.php Essentially It should start with item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4 with item 1 displaying its description. After 5 seconds the order should be item 2, item 3, item 4, item 1 with item 2 displaying its description. After 5 seconds the order should be item 3, item 4, item 1, item 2 with item 3 displaying its description etc etc The code I just updated on the link I posted, kinda does it but for some reason it gets abit message after the first few loops

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/jquery/1.4.js"></script>
<script>

var Model = {}
 jQuery( function(){ Model.FeatureBar.init(jQuery('.features')) } );

Model.FeatureBar = {
        current:0,
        items:{},
        init: function init(options){

            var me = this;
            me.triggers = []
            me.slides = []
            this.container = jQuery('#features');

            jQuery('.feature').each(function(i){
                me.triggers[i] = {url: jQuery(this).children('.feature-title a').href, title: jQuery(this).children('.feature-title'),description:jQuery(this).children('.feature-description')}
                me.slides[i] = {image: jQuery(this).children('.feature-image')}
            });

            for(var i in this.slides){
                this.slides[i].image.hide();
                this.triggers[i].description.hide();
            }
            Model.FeatureBar.goToItem(0);
            setInterval(function(){Model.FeatureBar.next()},5000);
        },
        next: function next(){
            var i = (this.current+1 < this.triggers.length) ? this.current+1 : 0;
            this.goToItem(i);
        },
        previous: function previous(){
            var i = (this.current-1 > 1) ? this.current-1 : this.triggers.length;
            this.goToItem(i);
        },
        goToItem: function goToItem(i) {
            if (!this.slides[i]) {
                throw 'Slide out of range';
            }
            this.triggers[this.current].description.slideUp();
            this.triggers[i].description.slideDown();

            this.slides[this.current].image.hide();
            this.slides[i].image.show();

            this.current = i;
        },
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="features">
            <div class="feature current">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="feature-image">
                <a href="google.com"><img src="/design/images/miss.png"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="feature-title"><a href="google.com">Item 1</a></h2>
            <p style="display: none;" class="feature-description"><a href="google.com">Item 1 description</a></p>
        </div>

            <div class="feature">
                            <div class="movie-cover">
                    <a href="/movie/movie"><img src="/image2.png" alt="" title=""></a>
                </div>
                        <div style="display: block;" class="feature-image">
                <a href="/rude/movie"><img src="/images/Featured/rude.png"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="feature-title"><a href="/rude/movie">Item 2</a></h2>

            <p style="display: block;" class="feature-description"><a href="/rude/movie">Item 2 description</a></p>
        </div>
            <div class="feature">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="feature-image">
                <a href="/pis/movie"><img src="/image3.png"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="feature-title"><a href="/pis/movie">Item 3</a></h2>
            <p style="display: none;" class="feature-description"><a href="/pis/movie">Item 3 description</a></p>

        </div>
            <div class="feature">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="feature-image">
                <a href="what.com"><img src="/images/Featured/indie.png"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="feature-title"><a href="what.com">Item 4</a></h2>
            <p style="display: none;" class="feature-description"><a href="what.com">Item 4 description</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because it doesn't do anything here. If I run you code I get the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Model`. So there is something missing here. It's very difficult to help if we can't reproduce your problem! And what do you mean by "it cuts off as it goes below #features"

Comment: okay, now the javascript is working, but I still don't know what you mean by "it cuts off as it goes below #features" perhaps you should provide some css, too. Because if I understand you correctly it could be a design problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do this:

```
$('.feature-description').each(function (i,n){
    var parent = $(n).closest('.feature');
    $(n).prependTo(parent);
});
```

This will take each "feature-description" put it to the begining/top of the parent ".feature"
Where to put the code? Well it depends when you want it to change places.

if you want it on page load. then put it on yout init function...

Hope it helps

Comment: Where would you put that?

Basically for example: item 1 is there to begin with, 5 seconds later, item 2 scrolls up, then item 3, then item 4. However due to design constraints the height of the box cuts off item 4s description.

What I would like is the item currently being looped & displayed to move to the top.

Comment: Its probably easier for you to paste the code into a html file and put a copy of jquery 1.4 in.

Comment: you are very confusing man... Do you need the element to move places?... or do you need an effect that slides the items up? if you have seen this done on other websites so we have an idea how it works.

Comment: Here is an example url:

http://forums.wuggawoo.co.uk/example.php

Essentially It should start with item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4 with item 1 displaying its description.

After 5 seconds the order should be item 2, item 3, item 4, item 1 with item 2 displaying its description.

After 5 seconds the order should be item 3, item 4, item 1, item 2 with item 3 displaying its description 

etc etc

The code I just updated on the link I posted, kinda does it but for some reason it gets abit message after the first few loops